# How to make margin more that mt-5 or mb-5 in bootstrap4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a form that I need it's margin-top to be 100px. 
Can I have this margin with bootstrap classes or I need to define a custom class for it?

```
<form class="mt-5">
</form>
```

Maximum margin-top that I can achieve here is `48px`

Comment: Just define them in your layout file. `.mt-6: margin-top: 60px;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nop, but you can simply :

make another class - if you plan on reusing that class :

```
.mt-100 { margin-top: 100px; }
```

or give that form a identifier class - if it's just for that form, and it doesn't already have a specific identifier class:

```
.myForm { margin-top: 100px; }
```

No need to complicate things here. Simple and readable, and move on with your code :) Good luck!